# Set arbitrary page numbers in pdf file

Tags: pdftex, pdf, page-numbering

When I am using different `\pagenumbering`s in a document, the PDF viewer shows the right page numbers, that is pages i, ii, etc... for `\pagenumbering{roman}` and 1, 2, etc... for `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for instance.

I wonder if it is possible to make the PDF viewer print anything as a page number. Since using LaTeX, the only possible options for page numbering are `arabic`, `roman`, `Roman`, `alpha` and `Alpha`, my goal is to make the PDF viewer print something else than what LaTeX would print by using the command `\thepage`. To be more specific, I'd like my title page to be "numbered" by the label "Title" in the PDF viewer for instance.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I am aware my question is not very well formulated but I have troubles to exactly explain what I wish, I still hope you'll understand!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I compile the following document, the adobe reader shows "Title (1 of 2)" as page number of the first page and " 2 (2 of 2)" of the second. But it also depends on the settings in the reader: you must activate "show logical page numbers".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thepage{Title}
abc
\newpage
\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
abc

\end{document}
```